# Como mesclar Javascript com PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Utilizo PHP, quando necessário, utilizo Javascript, mas o básico do básico.

Preciso capturar a resolução de tela do cliente, acredito que não seja possível em PHP por ser necessário uma linguagem client-side (Javascript).

Não estou sabendo como mesclar isso sendo que meu arquivo é PHP, um arquivo de funções, então preciso injetar o javascript no meio da função em PHP e passar o valor da variável em javascript para a variável em PHP, em seguida estas variáveis PHP entram em um array.

Segue o que estou tentando:

```
echo "<script>
          var width = screen.width;
          var height = screen.height;
      </script>";  
$width_screen = "<script>width</script>";
$height_screen = "<script>height</script>";
```

Comment: Acho que a tua pergunta refere um problema comum que já tem resposta na pergunta que indiquei. Se ainda tiveres dúvida diz, ou edita/coloca uma pergunta mais específica.

Comment: @Sergio, você tem razão, obrigado e podemos desconsiderar esta minha pergunta.